# Get base or inherited roles from Role or User object

Tags: security, role-management, permissions

Is there any way from an API level to obtain a list of roles which are "base" roles from an existing Role object? i.e. the roles which would grant inherited read access?

I've noticed that when querying a users roles via

```
Sitecore.Context.User.Roles
```

these inherited or "base" roles are not listed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to get a base roles for role, you can use the `GetRolesForRole(Role role, bool includeIndirectMembership)` method of `RolesInRolesManager`.

For example, if you need to get a base roles for each role of user, you can use something like below:

```
foreach (var role in Sitecore.Context.User.Roles)
{
    var basedRoldes = RolesInRolesManager.GetRolesForRole(role, true);
}
```

The `RolesInRolesManager` is defined at the `Sitecore.Security.Accounts` namespace.

If includeIndirectMembership flag is false, the method will return just a base roles for role. If flag is true, the method will also return a base roles of each base role.